# Passing data to child component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a github search app with the github api but I have some problems with passing data to child component. When the user clicked the view profile button, URL will be user/userID and it will show the profile details only in the child component. I watch some tutorials about it, but when I apply the ones shown in the tutorials, the profile details are listed on the main page not in the child component.
I only need profile details in the profile component.

home.component.html:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="profile" (keyup)="findProfile()" class="input">
<div>
  <ng-template [ngIf]="profile !== '' && user" >
    <img [src]="user.avatar_url" alt="" class="userAvatar">
    <p>Username: {{user.login}}</p>
    <p>Location: {{user.location}}</p>
    <p>E-mail: {{user.email}}</p>
    <p>Blog Link: {{user.blog}}</p>
    <p>Member Since: {{user.created_at}}</p>
    <button [routerLink]="['', user.login.toLowerCase(), user.id ]" class="viewProfileButton">View Profile</button>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

home.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../http.service';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  profile: any;
  constructor(private userData: HttpService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  findProfile() {
    this.userData.updateProfile(this.profile);
    this.userData.getUser().subscribe((result) => {
      this.user = result;
      console.warn(this.user);
    });
  }
}
```

profile.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpService } from 'src/app/http.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.scss']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  userID: any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
      params => this.userID = params['userID']
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most recommended way to pass the data from parent to child component is the use of  `@Input()` and `@Output()` decorators in angular.

[Please review the official docs to know more about @Input and @Output decorators.](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

Comment: I tried this way but parent and child component rendering in the same page. I want parent and child components in the different url paths, when I go to child component's url I should only see profile details in there. I don't know if I could explain myself enough.

Comment: If you want different url paths then use 'children' aray in routerConfig object in router.module file and use <router-outlet> to properly load the children of same parent. Refer https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes to learn more about the children